# Android : SQLite row not inserted in a table even no errors in insertion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I have an issue in the below. The insertion instructions were executed without any errors, but i can't figure out why the record is not writen in the table which remains always empty.

Method used to write the row:

```
public void addFBbitmap(String ID_FB, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException{
        qDb.beginTransaction();
        try{
            String sql   =   "INSERT INTO FB_ATTRS (ID_FB, IM_FB) VALUES(?,?)";
            SQLiteStatement insertStmt = qDb.compileStatement(sql);
            insertStmt.clearBindings();
            insertStmt.bindString(1, ID_FB);
            insertStmt.bindBlob(2, image);
            insertStmt.executeInsert();
            qDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
            qDb.endTransaction();
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, " Row inserted");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Error occured");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

the qDB (SQLiteDatabase) is created as below:

```
    private SQLiteDatabase qDb;
    qDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(dbPath))).append("myAppDB.db").toString(), null, 16);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest that you consider ***Returns
long - the row ID of the last row inserted, if this insert is successful. -1 otherwise.*** along with ***SQLException  If the SQL string is invalid for some reason*** [executeInsert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#executeInsert%28%29). My guess is that you get a -1 from `executeInsert`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I verified the result of "executeInsert()" method and it returns 1, which means that the insert is performed successfully. I'm still searching for what might be wrong in the code.

Comment: How are you checking the table?

Comment: I check the table but querying all the records from the table.                              I figured out the issue, which resides in the main activity in which i call the creation of the database (Copying it from Assets to Local storage and deleting the local DB if found) . I set the database to be deleted only onUpgrade:                                                                                                          
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {qCtx.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME_BDD));}

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue if deleting the database on every App run, which is wrong when the data changes. I solved the issue by deleting only the database when it's upgraded :

```
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{qCtx.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME_BDD));}
```